# Bulb for my curio cabinet

Tags: electrical, lighting

Can I replace my Furnlite FC-910 50PAR20 120V with a GE Halogen FL25 Beam 38W 120V bulb?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. What sort of fixture is this in?

Comment: You can get a (dimmable) PAR20 LED for under $10. At 6W it'll cost significantly less to run than either halogen or incandescent, generate almost no heat, and if you use it for 3 hrs/day it should last over 20 years.

Comment: Sylvania and GE are fine brands of LED bulb, and indeed under $10.  Go 3000K if you want the slightly whiter halogen color, and go max CRI (e.g. 90) if you want color rendition better than halogen, and with low/no UV to damage items.  e.g. http://amzn.to/2jgUYQQ

Answer (score 2):

The 50PAR20 is a 50-watt bulb.  The halogen is 38W, so the *total* heat dumped into your cabinet will be less.  However, the halogen bulb itself will get a lot hotter than the PAR20, so if the bulb is enclosed (e.g. behind a translucent lens), you probably shouldn't use the halogen.  Further, if the bulb sits close to wood or other flammable materials (and theres' no metal liner to the socket area), you probably don't want to use it.  Even if it never leads to smoke, it might age the wood around the bulb.